# Can I set some attribute to a Mockito.mock(Class.class)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I'm currently working on unit-testing services with mockito and Junit 5. 
Here is the problematic part of my ServiceTest.java :

```
...

archiveMeasure=Mockito.mock(ArchiveMeasure.class);
previsionHMeasure=Mockito.mock(PrevisionHMeasure.class);
ruleOccupationRate=Mockito.mock(Rule.class);
calculateIndicatorService=Mockito.mock(CalculateIndicatorService.class);

@Test
    public void DefiniteSectionThatBecomesDark_returnTrue() {
        //Arrange
        ruleOccupationRate.setThreshold(25);
        archiveMeasure.setOccupationRate(30);
        previsionHMeasure.setOccupationRate(30);
        boolean expected = true; 
        //Act

        boolean found = definiteSectionStateCongestionService.DefiniteSectionThatBecomesDark(archiveMeasure,previsionHMeasure,ruleOccupationRate);
        //Assert
        assertEquals(found,expected);
    }
```

And the service method to test is :

```
public boolean DefiniteSectionThatBecomesBright (       ArchiveMeasure archiveMeasure,
                                                        PrevisionHMeasure previsionHMeasure,
                                                        Rule ruleOccupationRate) {
        if ( calculateIndicatorsService.calculateActualCongestion(ruleOccupationRate.getThreshold(), archiveMeasure.getOccupationRate())==true || 
            previsionHMeasure.getOccupationRate() < ruleOccupationRate.getThreshold()) {
                return true;
            }
        else {
                return false;
            }
```

My problem is that I get a NullPointerException when I run the test, at ruleOccupationRate.getThreshold() I guess. I think that I can overcome this difficulty using lots of when().theReturn() for each getter involved in the Service. 
So my question is : Why the setters I used on the //Arrange part of my test aren't working ?
 Is it possible to set properties to a mock object, to avoid the mocking of every call of the getters ? 
If so, how may i proceed ?

Comment: `ruleOccupationRate.setThreshold(25)` this is not how you work with mocks.

Comment: `Mockito.when(ruleOccupationRate.getThreshold()).thenReturn(25)`

Comment: Here is a basic mockito tutorial. Suggest you read it. https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series

Comment: Ok @Michael so I absolutely need to use when().thenReturn() for each and every method called in the service i'm testing ?

Comment: I'm also going to note that just because you're writing a _unit_ test doesn't mean everything needs to be mocked.  Simple objects can still be real.  So `new RuleOccupationRate()... .setThreshold(25);` is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: That's how mocks work, yes. "*Is it possible to set properties to a mock object, to avoid the mocking of every call of the getters ?*" If this is what you want, then just use the real object. You are basically asking how to avoid the entire reason you would want a mock in the first place.

Comment: Right @BeUndead that would be easier in my case. Thx

Comment: Ok thank you @Michael